# Nextcord Discord Channel Message not Sending

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I'm attempting to make a variable for the log_channel and it is not allowing me to send a message. It works perfectly fine if the variable is in the command but not outside. I want to be able to send the message with the variable outside of the actual command.

Error:

```
nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Code:

```
logging = True
log_channel =  bot.get_channel(1005564776321138759)


@bot.slash_command()
async def kick(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, user: nextcord.Member, reason: str):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not authorized to run this command.", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Kicked {user.mention}", ephemeral=True)
        if logging is True:
            await log_channel.send(f"{user.mention} was kicked by {interaction.user.mention} for {reason}")
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
```

Comment: use `global log_channel` at the top of your command, or make the channel a botvar

Comment: Adding global to the top still gives the same error for some reason.

Comment: Oh right. This happens because you are trying to find a channel before the bot logs in and is ready.

Comment: It is under the on_ready event so It should be working?

Comment: `on_ready` callback is called when the bot is logged and connected to the websocket. It doesn't matter if `log_channel` was defined after `on_ready` override definition. Just assign a bot var in `on_ready` or `setup_hook`.

Comment: code outside function is executed before it runs bot - `bot.run(TOKEN)`. It doesn't wait for executing `on_ready()`. And `async def bot.run()` only define function but it doesn't run it - bot will run it after you run `bot.run(TOKEN)`. So you should get channel inside `on_ready()` and assign to global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`bot.get_channel` only works after the channels are cached which does not happen until after the bot is connected to Discord. Placing code outside of events / commands makes it execute immediately, before the bot is logged in.

I would recommend something like the following. `get_channel` is an efficient operation so is fine to call as needed.

```
LOG_CHANNEL_ID  = 1005564776321138759

async def send_log(content: str, **kwargs):
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
    await log_channel.send(content, **kwargs)

# elsewhere, when you want to log something
await send_log("content to log")
```

Alternatively, you can store the cached channel in a publicly accessible variable such as a bot attribute, but only assign it to the channel inside an `on_ready` listener or similar event that occurs after the bot is logged in.